# What does it mean by "veritable hive of activity."

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

> But the headquarters of the freshly rebranded Lemaire (formerly known as Christophe Lemaire) are a veritable hive of activity.

I would like to know what veritable hive of activity means. 
[original article](http://www.businessoffashion.com/articles/first-person/christophe-lemaire-says-cohesion-teamwork-important)

Comment: It's a cliche: the level of activity at the establishment is compared to that of bees in a beehive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Veritable" is used as an intensifier to describe the commotion in

> a hive of activity

which is the description for the activity in a beehive, which is usually filled with [*busy bees*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6VITuJvayNU&t=2m17s)

[image: here]
[here http://data1.whicdn.com/images/69262968/original.jpg](http://data1.whicdn.com/images/69262968/original.jpg)